# How To Create a Constructor Which Can Only be Called by Its Own Class?

Tags: c++, constructor

How can I create a constructor which only can be called by its own class? So when I have a Class `Foo` only make the constructor callable if it's called from a static member of `Foo`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make the constructor private:

```
class Foo
{
private:
   Foo();
public:
   static Foo* Create() { return new Foo(); }
}
```

And use the static method `Create()` to create an instance of the class.

Major reasons for making the constructor static can be to force the creation of the object by a factory, by a singleton, or in case when a class contains only static methods. I.e., a typical singleton implementation (single-threaded, for simplicity):

```
class Singleton
{
private:
   Singleton();
public:
   static Foo& GetInstance() { static Foo Instance; return Instance; }
}
```

Comment: A simple question: why did you preferred dynamic allocation here ?

Comment: @MatthieuM: Just as a typical usage example: factory method. Added an example with a reference.

Comment: Actually this "Meyers singleton" pattern (in the edited answer) works fine with multiple threads. This has always been true on most C++03 implementations, and it is mandated by the spec for C++11.

Comment: @Nemo: sure, but the question is not tagged C++11 so I added a comment. Just to bring the attention.

Comment: @Nemo: Well, the initialization works well with multiple threads, but it is up to the user to make it so that other operations on `Foo` are properly synchronization so it may be worth calling attention here. Not many beginners realize this just another form of a *global variable*.

Answer (score 10):

Make the constructor private:

```
class Foo
{
  Foo();
 public:
  static void usesFooConstructor();
  static Foo& makeInstance();  // only if you need a handle to an instance
};
```

Comment: I don't know. Especially considering the factory example of the other answer, which uses raw-pointers and dynamic memory, and has the double of upvotes...